# Hive Struct to String conversion

Tags: hadoop, struct, hive, hiveql

I have a table that has a struct in it - let's say:

```
create external table table1 ( 
    a int,
    b STRUCT <c:double,d:double>,
    e string
)
```

I perform select on this table and get something like -

> 1100  {"c":12.3,"d":45.6}    str

But then when I insert this data to another table -

```
create external table table2 (
    a string,
    b string,
    c string
)

insert overwrite table table2
select a,b,c
from table1;
```

I get the following strange behavior indicating that the **conversion between struct and string in hive doesn't work as expected**

```
select * from table2;
```

would result -

> 1100   12.345.6    str

the result is a kind of strange concatenation of values in the struct and even stranger things happen when dealing with more complex structs

1. Is there a way to prevent this auto conversion? Make hive throw an error in such cases?
2. Is there a clean way to change this auto conversion to work differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. We cannot prevent the auto conversion when directly `insert overwrite table table2
   select a,b,c
   from table1;` called. Whats happening behind is it just `concat` all the values from `struct`.
2. You can write generic UDF to play with `struct` ref: http://www.dataiku.com/blog/2013/05/01/a-complete-guide-to-writing-hive-udf.html

Quicker way:

if your intention is to get value out of struct and store it as a primitive value then try like below,

```
create external table table2 (
    a string,
    b_c string,
    b_d string,
    c string
)

insert overwrite table table2
select a,b.c,b.e,c
from table1;
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer!
Is there a way to make the UDF you suggested to write in 2 to be ran automatically in such cases?

Comment: No.. as far I know :)